# Help with a DIY tone board - selecting power supply wattage, grounding, and bypass switch

Tags: power-supply, power, grounding, watts, bypass

I plan to build a  tone board with this module

[AIYIMA HiFi 2.0 Class A Preamplifier Tone Board Power Amplifier Preamp Treble Midrange Bass Volume Control With ALPS](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005709432156.html#nav-specification)

The power supply is *"Supply voltage: dual AC12-18V, dual AC input (three lines) recommended dual AC15V (AC15V-0-AC15V)"*

I would appreciate an idiot's guide to the following issues.

1. Power transformers come in different ratings, how many watts do I need to power this board?
2. I want to fit a straight-through bypass switch. Is there a module I could use or can I fit a 2-position selector switch that selects through the board to the RCA outputs, or straight to the RCA outputs by passing the board?
3. I want to earth the box to the mains earth can I also run the ground to the same connection?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, but please be aware that shopping or product recommendation questions are off-topic and can result in your question being closed. Instead, ask a technical question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to already have a bridge rectifier, smoothing caps, and a pair of linear regulators. So you only need an external 15-0-15V transformer. (Actually that is stated in the text also.)

Power use is going to be small, it's basically just a few opamps. I would say 200mA will be more than enough, so a transformer of about 6VA or more should be fine. Here is one that is a bit too big, although that is not a problem:

https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/3979675.pdf